# Remember selected tab (bootstrap tabset) in Angular 5

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using tabset from Bootstrap (ngx-bootstrap.es2015.js) in a Angular 5 app. It works fine for the most part. However, when another component is displayed (and the component showing the tabset is hidden), and then you go back to the component showing the tabset, the tabset always shows the first tab as selected (even though perhaps the 3rd one was selected). Is there a way to "remember" which tab was active when returning to the "first" component?

Some code:

```
<tabset type="pills" [justified]="true" *ngIf="someCondition ">
      <tab *ngFor="let category of categories"
           heading="{{category.categoryNumber}} {{category.categoryName}}"
           (select)=setCategory(category.categoryNumber)>
      </tab>
    </tabset>

setCategory(categoryNumber) {
    this.currentCategory = categoryNumber;
    this._ref.detectChanges();
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I think the `destroyOnHide` input for `tabset` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: hmm, I tried [destroyOnHide]="false", but I get: Can't bind to 'destroyOnHide' since it isn't a known property of 'tabset

Comment: For some reason i thought you were using `ng-bootstrap`, which provides an out of the box solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to incorporate some state into your app in order for it to remember some piece of data. I've used [this](https://blog.nrwl.io/managing-state-in-angular-applications-22b75ef5625f) link in the past to learn more about creating such a state inside of my Angular applications.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, I usually use a flag of some sort, usually on a service that I'm injecting, which keeps the option selected.  Then I set the "active" class using ngClass based on the value on the service.  So something along the lines of this:

```
<tabset type="pills" [justified]="true" *ngIf="someCondition ">
  <tab *ngFor="let category of categories"
       heading="{{category.categoryNumber}} {{category.categoryName}}"
       [ngClass]="{ 'active' : category.categoryNumber === someSvc.selectedCategoryNumber }"
       (select)=setCategory(category.categoryNumber)>
  </tab>
</tabset>

constructor(private someSvc: MySomeService) { }

setCategory(categoryNumber) {
    this.someSvc.selectedCategoryNumber = categoryNumber;
    this.currentCategory = categoryNumber;
    this._ref.detectChanges();
    ...
}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way and hopefully someone will come along to show that to both of us, but it's always worked well enough for me since I almost always inject some sort of service to almost every single component.